# How to change UIBarButtonItem in return arrow?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5

I am looking through the attributes tab in Xcode 5 and trying to set the `UIBarbuttonItem` to look like the return button for ios7 which looks like this [image: this]
<sub>(source: [aplus.rs](http://aplus.rs/images/2013/ios7-mailapp.png))</sub>
 at the very top left the arrow. Does anyone know how to add this into a `UINavigationBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your identifier to custom & set an image for your button. there is no identifier available in attribute inspector which depicts Back button.Let me know if I am not clear.